# woocommerce: how to modify/extend product/item meta

Tags: wordpress, post, woocommerce, product, meta

we are using woocommerce and need to add a field for all products such as

`future_availabilty_quantity`

I'm not sure where woocommerce stores all product related attributes/fields.

Comment: All quantity related data is simply post meta

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce products are custom post types. Details are stored in wp_posts and wp_post_meta just as with any other type of post. To add a field, you would add it to the product page tabs. Here's a good article on adding custom fields to WooCommerce products: http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/